# Zabbix "Internal check is not supported" with item "zabbix[proxy,<name>,lastaccess]"

Tags: debian, monitoring, zabbix

I am trying to check the timestamp of last heart beat message received from Zabbix-Proxy. When i created an internal check, I see error message "internal check not supported".
So, i have another testing internal check with "zabbix[items]", and it work correctly.

What's wrong?

Zabbix server v2.2.1 (revision 40808) (09 December 2013)

Comment: Could you please specify the exact item key you are using for the heartbeat message? In the question title it says "zabbix[proxy,<name>,lastaccess]", but "<name>" is just a placeholder there - should be replaced with a real proxy name.

Comment: Is this item on a host monitored by server directly or by proxy?

Comment: @asaveljevs I replace <name> with correct proxe name, of cource.

Comment: I trying to add this item to host monitored by server directly and to another host,  monitored by proxy.

Comment: If you enable DebugLevel=4, does DBget_proxy_lastaccess() function appear there?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long time for a reply... but maybe could help someone else.
In my experience if you assign the item to the Zabbix Server, it works.
Off course it's mandatory to write the  of the proxy you want to check.